# Pan view won't work

Tags: shortcut, navigation

My middle mouse and shift button work on everything else, I even set it back to default factory settings, but it still doesn't work. I tried googling but nothing helped. I've also tried the alternative to the middle mouse, but it still doesn't work. I think the pan view is not working.

Comment: Does this happen even if you revert to factory settings? or on a specific file?

Comment: Yeah it still happens after I default back to factory settings

Comment: I think there is a problem in the pan view when opening directly a file and not first Blender and from there the file. This is the only way I found to move through the 3d view. Otherwize the Shift key is not working. Does anyone face the same?

Answer (score 0):

<sub>A comment might be too difficult to explain a test, so i post it as answer</sub>

---

What if you change your pan view to other shortcut, or manually add a new short cut to it?

It should be found in `3D View > 3D View (Global) > Pan View`

[image]

Add a new shortcut:
[image]

Comment: BTW I always change it to "shift + RMB" to pan view since "MMB" are too hard to press down in most of the mouse.